# Duplicate microsoft accounts

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

I'm trying to help my mum, who changed her office365 password (having forgotten the old one) and has since not received any emails.
While investigating the problem, I had to log in to a Microsoft account to download a troubleshooter (which didn't work). The login had two options, both with the same email address but one designated 'work or school account' and one designated 'personal account'. The work/school account didn't accept the new password, but the personal one did.

How do I get rid of the work/school account and switch entirely to the personal one that we know the password of? And will this lose the emails?

Comment: They are two distinct accounts. I have a similar situation. I own a business account [actually on BT, British Telecom] but they farm out the services to Office 365… so that becomes the one I have to login as 'work' and I have another private account set up for when I have to interact with MS for any other reason, like my Windows PC. The two are not connected & cannot be connected because they are different organisations.

Comment: The work/school account is managed by the organization administrator, it is recommended to find the administrator to reset the password. I would also suggest you.

Comment: For work/school account, you could also refer to "[Reset your work or school password using security info](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/reset-your-work-or-school-password-using-security-info-23dde81f-08bb-4776-ba72-e6b72b9dda9e)" on this [webpage](https://passwordreset.microsoftonline.com/).

Comment: @Emily - I'm able to reset my own password on the work account & in fact the company cannot do it. Since GDPR, frankly the changes made to how Office 365 works have made administration a nightmare - each user is now autonomous & the management options massively reduced. [As business owner I used to be able to add, remove, change aliases, reset passwords etc. Now I cannot. Each user is in charge of their own account. It's infuriating!]

Comment: Thank you both... Is there a way I can delete one of them? And is it possible to dissociate the work/school one from the company? (The company closed 3 years ago so finding the admin is going to be difficult)

Comment: And one final question, could the personal one receive emails and would they be the same emails?

Comment: The two accounts are not connected at all. You can delete either - but make sure you got the right one, you can't undo it. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/how-to-close-your-microsoft-account-c1b2d13f-4de6-6e1b-4a31-d9d668849979 I've never done this myself, so can't give any better advice.